# SIP | UDP | WP8 Simulator

Tags: udp, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-voip

We are developing VOIP Application, and right now testing over WP8 Emulator, i am able to establish call with the Mobile Phone, but nothing is audible at both end,

On Wireshark/Network traces, nothing is visible as UDP Packet, i could able to see SIP Log properly,

and in my code i can see log

```
[172] Bytes send to ABC.XYZ.AQW.ASD:PPPP Time:354
```

and no exception is thrown , i.e. its safe to assume, data sent from the Application ( Emulator ) to the destination port

But its not being shown in the Wireshark, Do i need to apply any specific filter to capture the UDP Log, i was able to see easily when i was on WP7 and developing application on MSVS2K10, but giving problem when i am on WP8 Emulator and Developing on W8/MSVS2k12.

Comment: Which NIC are you attaching Wireshark too? The Windows 8 emulator is a hyper-v images, so create a virtual NIC which is bridge to your physical outbound internet connection. Double check to see if you are monitoring the correct connection.

Comment: I'll also recommend getting a device for VoIP development.